# Calculate the outside (border) of intersecting circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I am developing a real-time strategy game where you are able to move a number of your units around a map. When a unit is selected, I draw a circle around that unit to represent that unit's vision range. However, when multiple units are selected their vision range circles overlap, and it ends up looking quite messy.

Here is an example of 72 units arranged in a box all selected:
[all units selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGTPy.png)

And here is what it looks like zoomed out:
[zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW5Of.png)

What I would like is an equation so that I can represent just the outside borders of those circles, which in this example would look something like a rounded rectangle. My inputs would be the individual unit positions, represented in my case as lat,lng (but x,y I suppose would also be OK), as well as the diameter of each unit's circle (which in this case are all the same at 50 metres, but won't always be).

Is there any formula that can calculate and represent this polygon, such that it is drawable using common computer drawing APIs (such as HTML5 canvas)?

Many thanks,
Arj

Comment: One possible solution to your problem is to actually map a solid disk instead of only a circle. With the right amount of transparency this looks even better than the combined boundaries of every field of vision.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - believe me I've tried. No matter how low you set the transparency, when the circles overlap at some point they become completely opaque. And I must always be able to show the map underneath as well as other units. It also looks messier because there is now too much to visually display - units, circles as well as 10-20 different shades of whatever colour the circle fill is. It just doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeking is called in the literature, computing the union of
disks. There is no simple algorithm known. Here are two possible routes:

(1) Use the [power diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram) to construct the boundary of the union of disks,
as explained in this paper:

> Imai, Hiroshi, Masao Iri, and Kazuo Murota. "Voronoi diagram in the Laguerre geometry and its applications." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 14, no. 1 (1985): 93-105.
>   [Journal link](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0214006).

(2) Use the CGAL package for Boolean operations on "general polygons":
[CGAL manual link](https://doc.cgal.org/Manual/3.5/doc_html/cgal_manual/Boolean_set_operations_2/Chapter_main.html).

Comment: Thanks very much Joseph. Those links are certainly interesting, but it looks like you're right - there doesn't appear to be a simple algorithm to calculate the borders alone (rather than just intersections, overlaps etc.). Due to the effort involved vs. the (relatively) minor aesthetic improvement in my use case, I'll probably end up drawing a circle that represents the average or maximum circumference of all intersecting points.